# What tool can I use to definitely kill a process on Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, task-manager

Can anyone recommend an application (preferably usb-portable that doesn't require setup)
That really kills a process immediately in windows XP?

I ask this because often when I need to use the XP task manager it seems to want to go about it "the polite way" and sometimes crashed programs don't quit or take a minute to shut down.

I need a real stone cold killer, not a pushover-could-you-please-quit-now-no?-ok-sorry-program

**Edit** I'm sorry if it wasn't clear previously but I did mean the situation when even the "End process" command in Process tab of the task manager doesn't kill a program, however one of the answers did point me to the "End Process Tree" command which I've never noticed (when right clicking on the process)

Comment: if a solution does in fact answer your question, please mark it as correct as per SE guidelines :)

Comment: @g19fanatic, i usually give it a day before I accept an answer that has no definite 100% correct answer

Comment: Some processes simply can't be terminated. Probably the most common reason is that the process has issued an I/O request that hasn't completed. Such a process can't be allowed to disappear, because if it did, and the I/O request completed later, the I/O transfer might corrupt resources that the process formerly owned. This could corrupt literally anything in the system. It's not the process's fault; it's the fault of whatever driver is holding the I/O request without supporting I/O cancellation. There is no general solution for this problem, so the OS simply won't let the process go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If normal Task Manager fails you can get Sysinternals [Process Explorer](http://live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe). It allows you to kill services too so it's a lot better then standard TaskMgr. This is useful in case some service has hung that even `stop/restart` doesn't work on it.

Answer (score 4):

I usually will use the "End Process Tree" option in the Processes tab of the Task Manager. I find this method to kill the problem much faster and with better results that just using "End Process" by itself.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about that one

Comment: This is only available from the context menu, whereas the basic "End Process" option has a button as well.

Answer (score 3):

Using the **End Process** option on the Processes tab of the Task Manager is (or at least should be) a sure fire way of terminating an application.

The only problem you might have is that if an application starts several processes you need to find and kill the "master" process to ensure that it all stops in one go.

Comment: When "End Process" is not working, program has crashed in a way it can't be terminated (without reboot). There is no magical process killer application that's going to help in that case.

Comment: @Olli - hence the "or at least should be" part :)

Comment: yes, I was just predicting that there will be comments saying "No, I had case when it didn't work. I want better program"

Answer (score 3):

[**Process Explorer**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) has this functionality.

[image]

Disable the entry pointed to by the arrow.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Wixkill](http://windows.xkill.free.fr/download.html). It kills bothering apps on your system just like `xkill` in Linux does. [Here](http://solo-dev.deviantart.com/art/Windows-xKill-100737525) is an improved version. It's free and portable (just 17.9 KB).